# Public map value returns null after first batch iteration

Tags: batch, map, variable-scope

I'm working on a CSV parser that I now want to handle the processing of more records.

By doing so I'm porting my existing apex class to a batch class.

I execute my batch with: `Database.executeBatch(new CSVMachineBatcher(bodyLines), batchNumber);`

Where `bodyLines` is `\n` separated rows from a CSV.

In the constructor I set the `bodyLinesReceived` received from the above executeBatch to a new public variable `bodyLines` in batch class.

```
    public List<string> bodyLines{get;set;}
    global CSVMachineBatcher(List<String> bodyLinesReceived){
        bodyLines = bodyLinesReceived;
    }
```

In my batch class (CSVMachineBatcher) start method I get the column headers to know which fields these values map to by doing the following:

```
public Map<Integer,String> headerMap{get;set;}

global List<String> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
    headerMap = new Map<String,String>();

    List<string> headerKeys = bodyLines[0].split(',');
    for (integer key=0; key < headerKeys.size(); key++) {
        headerMap.put(key, headerKeys[key].trim());
    }

    system.debug('headerMap: ' + headerMap);

    bodyLines.remove(0);

    return bodyLines;
}
```

With every iteration of a batch I execute (essentially converting each "row" of CSV into an sObject:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<String> scope){

    bodyLines = scope; 

    for(row=0; row < bodyLines.size(); row++) {

            System.debug('Value Line: '+ bodyLines[row]);

            convertToDataRecord(bodyLines[row]);


    }
```

Where I subsequently call on the headerMap generated in the start function to find out which field the currently value relates to based on it's position. Ex: If I'm on the third row parsing this row and the value is 15 and the third row in the headerMap is Age__c I know to populate the Age__c field with this value:

```
String currentKey = headerMap.get(i);
```

However, after the first batch iteration the headerMap is returning null. Resulting in Attempt to de-reference null object error when attempting to get the value from the map based on the key.

Do public Maps or other primitive type variable not persist in a Batch Class?

Comment: I assume you mean `column`, not `row` ; does your batch class implement `Database.Stateful` ?. Also, your headerMap would be more understandable if `Map<Integer,String> fieldnameByTokenPosition`

Comment: I do mean row, after I extract the column headers from row 0, I am parsing and consuming each row. Will update to integer, that was pretty dumb of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables only maintain state in a batch class if the batch class implements `Database.Stateful`

Credit: @cropredy